# Sonicwall 3500/3600 blocking port scan on LAN

Tags: sonicwall

I'm attempting to lock port scanning on LAN (X0) interface. So far it's unsuccessful. The old 3500 seems to be able to block this but I can't find which setting blocks that. How do I block port scan between LAN clients on NSA 3600?

Comment: Traffic between LAN clients doesn't transit the firewall, so the firewall can't block port scanning between LAN clients.

Comment: What version of the firmware are you on?